# Get selected radio button list value from radio buttons inside a Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, radiobuttonlist

I have a radiobuttonlist inside a repeater.  I am showing a screenshot of what this looks like.  I have column headers inside the header template of the repeater.  In the item template, I have the 4 fields/columns.  The 3rd field is a radio button list.  If, for example, I select the "Yes" radio button in the "Test Task 2" row - I need to postback and save the value of that record (back to a database).  My repeater could potentially display many rows of fields and radio button lists.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is this radio button list of seperate radio button for Yes, No and N/A ?

Comment: Yes, No, and N/A are ListItem's as part of one Radion Button List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            // Checking the item is a data item
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var rdbList = item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1") as RadioButtonList;
                // Get the selected value
                string selected = rdbList.SelectedValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the suggested btnSave_Click method assigned to OnSelectedIndexChanged on the RadioButtonList.  I also set AutoPostBack to "true".  When I select a different radiobutton, my page is posting back, but not firing the btnSave_Click method.  How do I wire that up?

Comment: Question I just asked was answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707193/radiobuttonlist-inside-repeater-onselectedindexchanged-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Repeater1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < Repeater1.Items.Count; count++)
    {
        RadioButton rd1 = (RadioButton )Repeater1.Items[count].FindControl("ID1");
        RadioButton rd2 = (RadioButton )Repeater1.Items[count].FindControl("ID2");
        RadioButton rd3 = (RadioButton )Repeater1.Items[count].FindControl("ID3");
        if (rd1.Checked)
        {

        }
        if (rd2.Checked)
        {

        }
       if (rd3.Checked)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something in gridview like this hope this can help you
Let us consider we have 2 buttons

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb_Yes" runat="server" GroupName="GpName" Text="Yes" OnCheckedChanged="rb_Yes_Click" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb_No" runat="server" GroupName="GpName" Text="No" OnCheckedChanged="rb_No_Click" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Just use the oncheckedChanged event for post back
and in .cs Page use the code something like this I m sure this can help you

```
protected void rb_Yes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    RadioButton rb_Yes = (RadioButton)sender;
    GridViewRow grid_row = (GridViewRow)rb_Yes.NamingContainer;
    if(((RadioButton)grid_row.FindControl("rb_Yes")).Checked==true)
    {
//Action that you want to implement
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you