# RadioButtonList Inside Repeater OnSelectedIndexChanged Not Firing

Tags: asp.net, repeater, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList inside a Repeater.  I have AutoPostback set to "true" and the OnSelectedIndexChanged defined.  When I selected a different radiobutton in my list the page does postback, but my defined OnSelectedIndexChanged event is not catching or firing.  Not sure what I am missing.  Here is my markup and codebehind:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Paste your code here instead of image.

Comment: Are you rebinding the repeater on postbacks? If so, it will probably lose the radiobuttonlist's state. Please post your code where you are binding the repeater.

Comment: I am binding the repeater on Page_Load.

Comment: You should only bind during Page_Load when it is not a postback.  Otherwise, bind after you have completed your other processing tasks (e.g. event handlers).  Binding before you process events can cause this type of issue as well as other validation exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the repeater's itemcreated event to bind your eventhandler:

```
 protected void Repeater!_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                {
                   e.item.FindControl("TaskRadioButtonList").SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(TaskRadioButtonList_OnSelectedIndexChanged);

                }
        }
```